# Get-SqlErrorLog is not recognized during execution

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I installed SQLServer tools and was successfully running the Get-SQLErrorLog command.  After a restart of PowerShell, attempts to run the exact same call `Get-SQLErrorLog` give:

> Get-SqlErrorLog : The term 'Get-SqlErrorLog' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...

When I check, I see:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name SQL*

    Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                 
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                 
Script     21.1.18218 SqlServer                           {Add-RoleMember, Add-SqlAvailabilityDatabase, Add-SqlAvailabilityGroupListenerStaticIp, Add-Sq...


    Directory: D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\PowerShell\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                 
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                 
Manifest   1.0        SQLPS                               {Backup-SqlDatabase, Save-SqlMigrationReport, Add-SqlAvailabilityDatabase, Add-SqlAvailability...
```

Can anyone explain how to get the functions I was calling earlier to work?

Answer (score 1):

Run `Import-Module SqlServer`, as the module won't be imported by default.

If you want to import the module by default, then type `$profile` into the terminal, to find out the location of the file. Then open (or create, if it doesn't) that file and enter `Import-Module SqlServer` into the file and save. Any future sessions will then load the module.

Comment: I ran "Import-Module SqlServer" which does not return any error but also does not appear to do anything.  "Get-SqlErrorLog" continues to fail with the same error.

Comment: Wow.  I just closed and reopened PowerShell and now the Get-SQLErrorLog command is working.

Comment: @Ken is this still an issue, if not this is a good candidate to mark as an answer.